# Call a function with user arguments as function name and its arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to C++, and would appreciate if you could help me with this.

Suppose I have a few functions defined:

```
double square(float x) {return x*x}
double cube (float x) {return x*x*x}
read_lib(const string &file_name)
```

Now, when my user inputs `square 10`, I want to call the square function, with `10` as the argument, and return `100`.

Similarly, when my user inputs `cube 3`, I want to return `27`.

Similarly, when my user inputs `read_lib /path/to/file/library.gz`, I want to process the file.

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{ 
    string quote;
    while(quote != "quit") {

        cout << "Enter: - ";
        string sa[70];
        getline(cin, quote);
        istringstream iss(quote);
        int count = 0;

        while(iss){
            string sub;
            iss>>sub;
            if(sub == "") 
                break;
            sa[count] = sub;
            cout << "sub "<<count <<" is " << sa[count]<<endl;
            count ++; 
        }

        string str = sa[0] + "(" + sa[1] + ")"; 
        // How do I dynamically switch quotations depending on sa[0]
        cout << "command executed was "<< str.c_str() <<endl;
        system(str.c_str());
    }
}
```

If this cannot work, what other option do I have to get the intended result?

Please help me re-write this code if I have messed up too much.

This is how it executes:

```
 sub 0 is cube

 sub 1 is 3

 command executed was cube ("3")

sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `"3"'
sh: -c: line 0: `cube ("3")'
```

Comment: Are you reading any C++ book?

Comment: From a security point of vue, it's hard to do worse than passing arbitrary user data to `std::system`.

Comment: How is this code relevant to the functions you mentioned at the beginning?  Where is your complete program?  Where are any error messages that you might be getting?  Where is any research on this problem (whatever it is) that you are having?  What is the intended result?

Comment: why do you write this code at all? No offense, but it seems a bit pointless to write a c++ program that does nothing else than forwarding what the user typed to a `system` call. Isnt it easier if you type `square(10)` directly into your console?

Comment: @tobi303 This is just a example. I have a large tool with interactive c++ interface. All the functions will be in background and the user will want to have leniency in c++ syntax.

Comment: if this is just an example you should mention it, because honestly it does not look like a [mcve] for the problem you describe ;)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I didn't know typing commands at a shell prompt is a security breach...

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Is there any other way to do this. I already have background ready. I am just nnot sure how to make a intractive window. But you are right this could be fatal

Comment: @Drt I am sorry. I just posted the main(). the squre and cube are return statements x*x.The intended result is executing the arg[0] funct on argv[1] and returning the result

Comment: @ChinmoyKulkarni if you want to read only argv[1] and argv[2] then you might as well just construct two strings directly: `string command(argv[1]);` and `string argument(argv[2]);`. And you'd want to use argv[1] and argv[2] since argv[0] is the command used to execute your program.

Comment: @Carl I still don't get you. argv[0] could be "square" or "root". and argv[1] could be any double. How do I execute argv[0](string to function ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple parts to your goal:

- Parsing input.
- Parsing arguments to pass them to the command function.
- Figuring out which command function to call.
- Displaying the results.

First, lets start with the functions you want to call:

```
double square(float x) {
    return static_cast<double>(x) * x;
}

double cube(float x) {
    return static_cast<double>(x) * x * x;
}
```

Now, we need a "command type," which we'll define as a function that takes a string as an argument and returns a string:

```
using command_fn = std::function<std::string(std::string const &)>;
```

Great, but the functions we have don't accept strings, and they don't return strings.  No matter, we will wrap them in a lambda that parses the arguments using standard input streaming operators, and formats the result into a string:

```
template <typename R, typename A>
command_fn create_command(R (*fn)(A)) {
    return [fn] (std::string const &string_arg) {
        std::istringstream s{string_arg};
        A arg;

        if (!(s >> arg)) {
            return std::string("Failed to convert argument");
        }

        return std::to_string(fn(arg));
    };
}
```

Now we can create an `std::map<std::string, command_fn>` that maps command names to the wrapper functions:

```
std::map<std::string, command_fn> commands{
    { "square", create_command(square) },
    { "cube", create_command(cube) }
};
```

Finally, we parse the input and dispatch the calls in a loop:

```
int main() {
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        auto space = line.find(' ');

        std::string cmd, arg;
        if (space == std::string::npos) {
            cmd = std::move(line);
        } else {
            cmd = line.substr(0, space);
            arg = line.substr(space + 1);
        }

        auto const &cmdfn = commands.find(cmd);

        if (cmdfn != commands.end()) {
            std::cout << cmdfn->second(arg) << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "No such command: " << cmd << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

([See a demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30e749dd31444503))

Some notes about this code:

- We only accept one argument per command. You may want to allow more than one argument. This could be implemented in the `create_command()` function by accepting a parameter pack for `A`.
- `create_command()` only checks if the conversion was successful. Ideally you would also want to make sure that the input string was totally consumed.
- `create_command()` will only instantiate for a function if:

  - The argument of the function is of a type for which there is a streaming input operator.
  - The return type is of a type that can be passed to `std::to_string()`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first of all you do not need an array of 70 strings in order to parse your commands. For your requirements, it looks like you're going to need to parse a command and then an argument. In this case I used an std::array, to create an array of 2 strings. However, you can make as many as you like, and then process the command in a loop, rather than manually with `command[0/1]`. Or use a vector if you need one command, and then some arguments.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string quote;
    array<string, 2> command;
    while (quote != "quit") {
        cout << "Enter: ";
        getline(cin, quote);

        auto separator = quote.find(' ');
        if (separator == string::npos) continue;

        command[0] = quote.substr(0, separator);
        command[1] = quote.substr(separator + 1);

        cout << "Command executed was " << command[0] << '(' << command[1] << ")\n";
    }
}
```

I also used the `string.find()` method to look for a space in the parsed command, and then if a space was not found, to continue awating valid input. Now, if the user entered quit, the program will still quit. At the bottom it will `cout` the command you entered for clarity. However, in order to call a function based on what was entered you would have to for example check the string in `command[0]` for a valid value, and then convert the argument in `command[1]` to the required type. For example, if an integer is required, convert it using `stoi(s)`.

Comment: Thanks. But I still did not see how it will call the command[0] function?

Comment: @ChinmoyKulkarni Make an `std::map<std::string, std::function<std::string(std::string)>>` and look up the function in the map.

Comment: You could pass it through an if statement:
`if (command[0] == "cube") cube(stoi(command[1]));`
Assuming you wanted an integer passed to cube. And of course assuming the user actually entered a number. If you don't know that, you might want to do some validation up front.

Comment: As I said this is an example without breaching privacy and legality. But I have more than a few thousand functions. Is using map still the best option?

Comment: @ChinmoyKulkarni Yes. *`system()` doesn't even do what you want.*

Comment: @cdhowie I see, then what could be the best method to do this? As suggested map all functions?

Comment: @ChinmoyKulkarni Yes. See my answer for a possible approach.

Comment: If you have thousands of functions and you want to distribute the registration of user-callable functions, you could create a class whose constructor inserts data into a singleton registry map, and then put static global variables of that class next to their corresponding functions.  (Then just be careful if there are static libraries involved to make sure there's something forcing all the machine object files containing such registration objects to get linked in.)

Comment: Or, maybe use some tool like Swig to create Python bindings to your functions, create a Python extension module out of your code, and then let Swig and Python handle all the dispatching for you. :)